# What is happening in this Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, loops

I have this below Javascript code that animates [expands/collapses] a group of DOM elements:

```
function animateHeight(children, animationDuration, changeTop) {
  const height = children.clientHeight;
  const frameDuration = (1 / 60) * 1000; // 60 fps
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const slideSomeMore = function (moved) {
      let next = window.performance.now() + frameDuration;
      while (moved < height) {
        if (window.performance.now() < next) {
          continue;
        }
        children.style.top = `${changeTop(moved, height)}px`;
        moved = moved + height / animationDuration;
        setTimeout(() => slideSomeMore(moved), 0);
        return;
      }
      resolve();
    };
    slideSomeMore(0);
  });
}
```

I am trying to figure out what is happening line by line and this is what I am thinking:

1. The Function `animateHeight` is called 3 parameters: the target dom elements, animation duration and finally the parameter that determines expansion or collapse.
2. We set the height of the target dom to a variable called height.
3. We create a variable `frameDuration` to set it to 60 fps;
4. A promise is created to run the actual animation in an async manner.
5. Within the promise a function slideSomeMore is created that takes parameter `moved`
6. Then, a variable `next` is created  by adding the time since the window was rendered plus 60 which is the `frameDuration` created in step 3.
7. We then enter a while loop as long as `moved` is less than `height`.

This is where it gets a bit challenging, any idea what is really happening here? I am unable to figure out what this while loop actually does?

Thanks

Comment: "*I am unable to figure out what this while loop actually does?*" blocks the entire thread for the duration of one frame.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this **probably** belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), another site in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @AndrewL64 why? It's not about suggesting improvements to the code. And we do allow questions on explaining code here.

Comment: @AndrewL64 "*For licensing, moral, and procedural reasons, we cannot review code written by other programmers. We expect you, as the author, to understand why the code is written the way that it is.*" https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @VLAZ True. I wasn't too sure hence the "probably". Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I read it like this (but I probably have one or more errors in here somewhere):

---

This code DEFINES the function `animateHeight` with 3 parameters:
`children` (a SINGLE element), `animationDuration`, and `changeTop` (a FUNCTION
with 2 parameters).

**In `animateHeight`:**

1. We GET the height of the `children` element, and bind it to a variable called
   `height`.
2. We define a variable, `frameDuration`, that will help us animate at 60 fps.
3. We create AND RETURN a promise to run the actual animation in an async manner.

   **In the promise:**

   1. We create a function called `slideSomeMore` with 1 parameter: `moved`.
   2. We call `slideSomeMore` (binding the argument `0` to the parameter).

      **In `slideSomeMore`:**

      1. We get the time for the next frame by adding `frameDuration` (which equals
         1000/60) to the current timestamp (in milliseconds); and we bind the result
         to `next`.
      2. We enter a while loop as long as `moved` is less than `height`.
      3. Once we exit the loop, we resolve the promise.

         **In the loop:**

         1. We wait (continuing to the next iteration without taking any action)
            until the time to render the next frame has arrived.
         2. We place the `top` of the `children` element (according to the output of
            the `changeTop` function).
         3. We increase `moved` by an amount equal to `height` divided by
            `animationDuration`.
         4. We call `slideSomeMore` recursively, passing in the new `moved` value
            (but we use `setTimeout(fn, 0)` to create a brief delay first).
         5. We exit the most recent call to the `slideSomeMore` function (but many
            recursive calls to `slideSomeMore` may have occured, and all of these
            will have to finish before we finally resolve the promise).